# Makefile: using variable with computed name as prerequisite

Tags: makefile

In Make it's possible to compute variable names in runtime using double-evaluation, like `$($(var))`.

I'm interested if it's possible somehow to make this work:

```
one.js_DEPS=a b
two.js_DEPS=c b

all: one.js two.js

%.js: $(%.js_DEPS)
    cat $^ > $@
```

I can make this work by declaring two rules with explicit dependencies, like this:

```
one.js: $(one.js_DEPS)
```

But this seems a bit anti-DRY. So I'm wondering if I miss something because make doesn't seem to understand me. I use GNU Make 3.81.

Comment: It seems that you're confusing targets and variables. In your example, `xxx.js_DEPS` are targets but you also try to expand them as variables.

Comment: Oh, I've just entered that in hurry and made a mistake. I'll fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` and implicit rules are somewhat second-class citizens in `make`, since variable expansion seems to happen before implicit rule expansion. So, in your above Makefile, `$(%.js_DEPS)` is expanded to the empty string before `%` is substituted.

Alternative:

```
 %.js: %.js_DEPS
     cat $^ > $@

 %.js_DEPS :
     cat $^ > $@

 .INTERMEDIATE: one.js_DEPS two.js_DEPS
```

or simply:

```
 one.js : a b
 two.js : c d
 %.js :
     cat $^ > $@
```

Comment: Yeah, I've done it right now as last one. Too bad % happens later than variable expansion (doesn't make that much sense honestly).

Comment: The `make` authors are strict with `%` rule chaining because they want dependency resolution to be simple enough to make it easy to see that quick termination is always guaranteed. At least that is my impression.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion).

```
JS := one.js two.js

all: $(JS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:

one.js_DEPS := a b
two.js_DEPS := c b

$(JS) : $$($$(@F)_DEPS)
    cat $^ > $@
```

But in fact, the goal can be achieved much simply, without using any GNU Make extensions, as [thiton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847601/thiton) has suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8744131/545027):

```
all: one.js two.js

one.js : a b
two.js : c b

%.js :
    cat $^ > $@
```